# Android TextView ellipsize wrong with RTL text

Tags: android, textview, right-to-left, ellipsis, ellipsize

I have an `AppCompatTextView` with some RTL text (Persian text, actually), and I set its `maxLines` to 1 and `ellipsize` value to `end`. But it doesn't work properly.

This is my `AppComaptTextView`:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/aditem_category"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="تست متن طولانی در نرم‌افزار اندروید که متن عمداً طولانی شده است"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="14sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1px"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iconCategory"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    ... Other properties ... />
```

**Please read the properties well. I typed those properties which were important to know.**
But what I get is:

[image: Screenshot]

The problems are:

1. The ellipsis is at right (**start** of an RTL text)
2. It has too much spacing, but there is room for some other words
3. The whole text is at left, but I set its `gravity` to `right|center_vertical`

*Note: when the text isn't long, none of these problems exist.*

**What should I do?**